# Specify git branch in slurm script

Tags: bash, git, cluster-computing, branch, slurm

I am running a slurm job submission file on a remote computing cluster. The job calls some scripts that are under a git repository that has two branches `main` and `test_branch`. In my directory on the remote cluster I can easily switch between the two using `git checkout`. I would like the slurm job to use the `test_branch` branch. However, if I just checkout that branch and then run the job submission file with `sbatch file.sh`, I can tell from the output file that it is using the scripts from `main` (there are certain bugs I fixed in `test_branch` but not `main`). I have tried adding `git checkout test_branch` directly into the job submission script, but that doesn't change anything. How can I fix this? Not sure if its relevant, but the job submission file is running a python script, and before calling the script I have the file activate a specific conda environment.

Edit:
Here is the script I am running.

```
# Clear the environment from any previously loaded modules
module purge > /dev/null 2>&1

# Load the module environment I need
module load anaconda 
conda activate my_env

# Checkout the right branch 
git checkout test_branch

# Run the actual python script
python ./my_python_script.py
```

Comment: With slurm jobs your have to activate things, set your PATH, etc, all inside the `file.sh` script, is that what you're doing? I would add some verbose printouts telling you where it's finding your files, e.g., submit a job that does a python script like `import mymodule; print(mymodule.__file__)` and check to see if it's picking up your python module where you're expecting it too. Add `which python` to make sure it's picking up Python from the right conda environment. The lack of interactivity for Slurm jobs means you have to do lots of print debugging.

Comment: The main gotchas are that anything you've setup in your interactive environment is not effective, only your dot files are used, and then you have to get your job file to set your PATH, go to the right directory, etc, etc. Plus, it took me a long time to setup my dotfiles correctly because it's not intuitive what gets run.

Comment: Hmm... @joanis, but why would I need to modify something on my PATH variable? I am already activating the environment (`module load anaconda`; `conda activate <environment_name>`) and checking out the branch (`git checkout test_branch`) in my job submission script.

Comment: In this case, `conda activate` is the command the modifies your PATH variable. So to translate my question in light of this precision: do you run that conda activate command inside your Slurm script? The rest of questions above are all about making sure that your selected environment is activated correctly.

Comment: Plz show your job script.

Comment: @joanis yes, the commands I listed are ones I have in the slurm job submission script. I have edited my question to show the script contents.

Comment: Showing your script was good, but please don't make us ask for debugging details bit by bit. Augment your script with `which python` and show us the result. Augment your script with something that shows the contents of the file it's going to execute. Augment your script with `git status` and `git show` and inspect the results. You still didn't provide us with enough debugging details to help you.

Comment: @joanis I apologize for not inlcuding enough information. It's hard for me to know what's helpfull to include. `which python` does point to what I belive is the correct python installation (its the one in the conda environment I am using). But adding `git status` and `git show` to the script isn't going to do anything since the script is being run outside the folder under git control (it just calls the files in that folder).

Comment: So maybe when you run `python ./my_python_script.py` you can put put `cat ./my_python_script.py` first to make sure it's the right version. Is that the script you're talking about not being the right version, or some library it loads? Let me be more explicit: what file exactly do you believe is the wrong version, where is it located, how do you access it?